# Delphi: Renaming an Invalid Folder

Tags: delphi, directory, file-rename

I have an application that creates invalid Directories... 
e.g. `c:\Program Files\somedirectory.`  - the period is a part of the directory name.

Now, I have tried everything that I know about renaming a file in delphi.

- RenameFile(file1,file2)
- MoveFile(File1,File2)
- etc...

I have tried getting the windows short path `ExtractShortPathName` but this just returns an empty string.
(to call in commandPrompt: "RENAME ShortOldName NewName")

Now I know I can manually do it in cmd but I am not about to spend the time to go through all my files and do it ;)

Here is a bit of my code:

```
xshortname := ExtractFileName(ExtractShortPathName(ns + oldName));
  xNewName := newName;

  cmdTxt :=  PWideChar('/C cd ' + ns);
  cmdTxt2 := PWideChar(cmdTxt + '&&' + ' RENAME ' + xshortname + ' ' + #34 + xNewName + #34);
  ShellExecute(0, nil, 'cmd.exe', cmdTxt2, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

I know shellExecute is not the best method to be using here.
I am just trying to get the stinker to work. I will worry about optimizing and proper Delphi coding later.

So my question is: Does anyone know of a function that will allow me to rename an invalid directory?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the standard Windows API function [MoveFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you pass the name of the folder in a special way:

```
MoveFile('\\?\D:\invalid_dir.', '\\?\D:\invalid_dir.fixed');
```

instead of

```
MoveFile('D:\invalid_dir.', 'D:\invalid_dir.fixed');
```

More about it can be found on MSDN under the ["Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) topic. Note that it specifically advises against putting trailing dots in file names.

Comment: Worked perfect. Thank you!  Searched everywhere. I knew SO would not disappoint.